# number of live connections

Tags: spring, jdbc

My application is using Websphere 6.1, Spring JDBC and oracle.I am using connection pooling to manage the connections.Is there any way to find out the number of connections active(alive) between the application and database at any point of time?.Can we have any indicator to let us know when a connection is/was dropped?

Comment: That's the job of the connection pool, whichever one you're using.

Comment: Can I fire any query from the database side to know the number of active connections the database is having?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to manage your connection pool via JMX. Spring has [excellent support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/jmx.html) for it. You just need to expose your connection pool bean via `org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter`. You can pick and choose the methods you want to expose. For example if you use DBCP you can use the method [BasicDataSource#getNumActive()](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/api-1.4/src-html/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html#line.701).

Comment: I have set Minimum connections=1, age timeout=0 and purge policy=entire pool. When the connections are to be purged then then will the minimum connection will also be purged.

Comment: Also if I have four connections(say) and Minimum connections=1 and purge policy=entire pool. If the connections are to be purged and the minimum connection is to be maintained (which 1 here) then which connection will be maintained indefinitely.As in the oldest one,the newest one or will any other logic be used.

Comment: I am pretty sure that it depends on the connection pool implementation. What are you using?